# Log4Net and memory consumption

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, log4net

I see that LogNet is typically instantiated with a static variable:

```
 static logger = LogManager.GetLogger(frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Stupid question, but:

1) Is this not a bit annoying --- ie. I must have this mess of a call in each logging piece of my code.

2) Does this not generate a lot of memory overhead --- ie. Every single one of my classes will be associated with a seperate logging class. 300 classes that use logging will force the use of 300 logging static variables? Seems strange.

Comment: It's not like a few hundred small objects are that expensive...

Comment: Well, it's still seems a pain from a coding perspective... For example, I must remember to instantiate the logger as 'static' each time. If I forget that then I get a performance penalty. Is there trickery to avoid this problem or simplify it?

Comment: Not sure about that, but the *GetLogger()* method **may be** supposed to return the same logger if called with the same argument. So if you have 300 instances of a class, you should have one single logger for all them.

Answer (score 2):

log4net maintains a repository of loggers, there is no need for you to make them static. Having a named logger per class is the recommended way, you do not need to worry about the "overhead" of having a few hundred loggers in memory. If that were a problem, you probably would need to remove logging altogether.

Logging is messy i.e. it clutters your code with stuff that is not really part of the business. Aspect orient programming might help you [there](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/Log4PostSharp).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need/have to use a static variable.  Typically my classes will look something like

```
public class Foo
{
   private ILog Logger;

   public Foo()
   {
       Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
   }

   //rest of class here

 }
```

This is fairly clean and until I have a memory problem, there's no point in early optimizing memory usage of the application.  However not all of my classes perform logging, so only those that do/need to will have this bit of code in them.  If everyone of your classes is logging then it sounds like you may be over-logging, either that or you're dealing with a  rather large application (based upon the fact you've got 300 classes writing out to the log).  If the later is the case then 300 instances of a logging class probably isn't a significant portion of your memory usage footprint.

You do have the option of setting up your logger as a named instance `ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("MyNamedLogger");` instead and using this "named" ILog instance across multiple classes.  Note that you will lose some of the usefulness of the logged messages due to the way the log messages are generally written out.  You could certainly compensate for that in several different ways.

Comment: -1 for the non static suggestion (leaving the same amount of wire-up code), +1 for mentioning named instance ;)

Comment: @KenHenderson: no need to use static as StefanEgli pointed out in his answer. Log4Net has a pool of named Loggers.

Comment: @Askolein - my first line mentions that you don't need a static variable.  Could you tell me what part of the answer mentions/implies the use of static so that I can update it to correctly reflect the intentions of my answer.